# Limit function on spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

When I have a limit statement on my spark data frame it still ends up reading the whole table/partition before it limits to the number of rows in the limit.

> spark.table("table_name").limit(1).show()

This ends up launching 30 tasks(one for each file in the table) when in my mmind it could have simply read the first file and returned.

Is there anyway that I can avoid this by turning on some optimization settings like what can be seen in hive(set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this and let me know your findings:

```
spark.table("table_name").take(1).foreach(println)
```

Comment: It does seem to have the expected functionality but here it brings the data to the executor immediately right? If I want to cache this dataframe and use it for other purposes that wouldnt be possible. The only reason that I included a show was to trigger an action to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to happen without retrieving the data to the executor in a fashion similar to limit and keep it as a dataframe?